# What is the best way to generate human readable ID like enum in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to generate unique ID for my game's assets in Unity3d.  I want a type-safe and fast comparable data type. Also, I don't want to use string because of it's breaking code by a typo in the code. I'm looking for something like `Sound.Button_Click` which accessible by auto complete.

I have tried to make a tool for the game designer to manage a file that contains an enum.
Unity3D serialises enums with `int` so when I delete an element from my assets' enum all serialized objects presenting wrong value. Whatever I'm not sure about making such tool is a good idea.

What is the best way to achieve it?

Comment: Manually assign values to the enum.

Comment: Do you think that creating this file is a good solution at all?

Comment: Create an enum if you need the enum.  It doesn't matter if you put it in its own file or not.  Asking us "is ____ a good solution" is polling for opinions, which is off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unity3D serialises enums with int so when I delete an element from my assets' enum all serialized objects presenting wrong value.

You can specify the enum values so that they won't change as items are removed.

If you do this:

```
enum Values
{
    Red, Blue, Green
}
```

Then modifying the enum (adding or removing items) can change the value.

If you do this

```
enum Values
{
    Red = 0,
    Blue = 1,
    Green = 2
}
```

Then adding or removing items won't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Often times i will do something like this:

```
public static class AssetKeys
{
   public static readonly string Skin1 = "skin1.bmp";
}
```

I'm not sure if its the best way but it at least avoids the issue of mistyping a string identifier

Comment: You could make the field `static`, or alternatively use a `const`. In either case the class can be made `static`.

Comment: The catch with this approach is that there is no way to define a method that takes one of the `AssetKeys` values as a parameter.  Methods that need one of these values are defined with a `string` parameter and there is no indication that it is supposed to be one of the strings from `AssetKeys`.